# Easy APNS, PHP, Swift 3, push notification issue

Tags: php, swift, push-notification

For people familiar with Easy APNS

I am watching a tutorial with Sergey Kargopolov on how to integrate swift 3 with php to send push notifications. Everything is going well except 1 thing. Everything is set up both in php and swift but when I run the app and enable push notifications nothing happens on the user end and nothing is sent to the database tables.

I get this error:

****Fatal error**:  Class 'mysqli' not found in **/home/MyApp/public_html/apns/classes/class_DbConnect.php** on line **178****

If anyone has done the tutorial and is familiar with the file help me out I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: It's a common issue, look in your  `/private/etc/php.ini` file and enable the mysqli extension

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks